# How to get gpio status on an output pin in ruby

Tags: gpio, ruby

I'm using the Pi to control some decorative lights.  I turn the lights on and off via cron scripts and would like to get status on the lights as well.  When I run the code below, it reports 'on' if the lights are on, but if they're off, they're turned on by the code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rpi_gpio'
RPi::GPIO.set_numbering :bcm
RPi::GPIO.setup 18, :as => :output

if RPi::GPIO.high? 18
    print "Lights are on\n"
else
    print "We're in the dark\n"
end
```

If I change the setup to => :input, the pin goes low immediately and the lights go out.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `but if they're off, they're turned on by the code` ..... how do you know that happens only if they are off? .... maybe the lights are always being turned on

Comment: The Ruby idiom of the trailing question mark normally means that something is being inquired about and the software returns the current value.  They are always being turned on, and this is wrong IMHO.

Comment: all i am saying is that the lights are not being turned on because of an `if` statement result .... they are being turned on by some other part of the program .... the lights probably turn on even if you remove the `if` statement

Comment: Sorry, no.  The software above is the whole of my 'status' command.  I've tested that line all by itself.   The line "if RPi::GPIO.high? 18"  turns the light on.  I'm shocked.  That's why I asked the question here.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue?

Comment: Sad to say, nope ...

Answer (score 0):

When you set a Pi GPIO to be an output (presumably line `RPi::GPIO.setup 18, :as => :output`) the GPIO level will be set to that last requested.

If the last level requested was high the GPIO will be high (on).

If the last level requested was low the GPIO will be low (off).

Comment: This makes sense, thanks, but doesn't cover every case:  After a power outage and reboot, the pin would be low even though my software set it high before the reboot.  There are also conditions where the cron job could fail and not turn on the lights.  I could look at the log, but was hoping for something more.

Comment: GPIO state is not preserved over a reboot.  I'd guess that all GPIO default to be low as far as the "last requested level" is concerned.